# How would you define a class in Boolean Logic?

Tags: logic

I am currently studying George Boole and how he denotes classes and syllogisms and understand his laws, just don't know how to define a class.

Answer (score 2):

Boolean logic is [propositional logic](https://www.iep.utm.edu/prop-log/).

To formalize [Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism) we need [predicate calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic).

The typical [categorical proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition) : "All S are P" will be symbolized as :

> $\forall x \ (S(x) \to P(x))$.

---

Quite different is the way George Boole used in his work [The Mathematical Analysis of Logic (1847)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/boole/#MathAnalLogi1847) to symbolize classes and formalize syllogisms.

The original formalism used by Boole had two possible interpretations : one in term of *classes* and one in term of *propositions*.

According to the first one, variables $x,y,\ldots$ stand for classes and the operation of "multiplication" : $xy$ stands for *intersection*.

The operation of "sum" : $x+y$ stands for *union* and "subtraction" stands for *complement*.

Finally, $1$ is the "universe" and $0$ is its complement.

Thus :

> $x(1-y)=0$

reads : "all $X$s are $Y$s".